# gtest unit tests target configuration file path

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

In my C++ application, I have a text file (dataFile.txt) that is installed on the Linux target machine in the following path:

```
/SoftwareHomeDir/Configuration/Application/dataFile.txt
```

This file exists on my Rational ClearCase source code environment under the path:

```
/ProjectName/config/Application/dataFile.txt
```

I am developping a unitTest in gtest that does following:

Read a specific data from `dataFile.txt` , if the data does not exist than write it into the file.

1) I am avoiding to create an environment variable to check whether I am in the compilation environment or the target machine. Then add additional test code in the final release. I really want to separate test code from final code.

2) I am not using any IDE (no visual studio, no qt, etc.), just notepad++

3) The compilatio. server is shared (access with a username, however the root folder "/" is shared. Which means that if I create the path `"/SoftwareHomeDir/Confiugration/Application/dataFile.txt"`, it will be visible by all users, and if another user is running his gtest unitTest, he may overwrite my file.

4) In the final code, the path to the dataFile is hard coded, and it is very costly (will take few seconds to run) to implement a filesearch(filename) method to look for the file in the entire hard drive before reading the file.

Question:

I am looking for a solution to unit-test my code in the compilation environment that is using  `/ProjectName/config/Application/dataFile.txt`

Comment: Either configure your app to work in both environments or change both environments to suit your app. As your app cannot be configured (you say the file path is hard coded), maybe you can change your environment? For example can you use a symlink with with the path the app expects that points to the actual file in your test environment?

Comment: I found an elegant solution, involving google gtest and gmock. This way I do not make changes to the release code. 

The solution is to actually create a getPath function that returns in the real app, the hard coded path, i.e, /AppInstallationFolder/Configuration/dataFile.txt 
I learned about gmock delegate to fake. This way I call a fake getPath function which returns the test path (or path of my configuration file in clearcase) using gmock
https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#delegating-calls-to-a-fake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to combine gmock with gtest as described by the link

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#delegating-calls-to-a-fake

The only modification I made to my code is that instead of defining the path to the configuration data using #define, I created a function getConfigFilePath() that returns the hardcoded path of the configuration file in the installed application. From here, I mocked the class and in my mock, I call a fake getConfigFilePath() that returns, when the real code is executing, the hardcoded path of the config file in the project tree in ClearCase. This is precisely what I was looking for.